# LazyColumn item position

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to get the value of the y position while the screen is scrolling?

I have a situation like this:

```
LazyColumn() {
    item {
      box()
      box()
      box()
      ScrollableTabRow(){}
    }
    itemsIndexed {...}
```

I need to know when the ScrollableTabRow moves past a certain position on y axis (for example lets say 100.dp )

I tried working with .scrollable()
(something like [scrollable](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/a3f001e83fbd8a5398e3bbddbe273c2a15980896/compose/foundation/foundation/samples/src/main/java/androidx/compose/foundation/samples/ScrollableSamples.kt))

and with scroll gesture filter
(something like [gesture](https://github.com/Foso/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/blob/9a8a3e8d8fcc2bdbcbd7318c133205182aee4624/compose/src/main/java/androidx/ui/demos/gestures/ScrollGestureFilterDemo.kt)

and with dragGestureFilter
but i cannot get it to work, am i doing something wrong, or is it just not possible?

Basically what i need to do is for the scrollable tab row to act as sticky header after it touches top of the screen.

What i wanted to do is, after scrollable row touches the top of the screen, create some sort of mockup for it at the top of the screen, but maybe there is some easier way?

App is written strictly in compose, so i dont have access to any of the libraries that provide such implementation

Comment: [Sticky headers](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1427927) will probably be in tomorrow's release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [stickyHeader](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScope#stickyHeader(kotlin.Function1)).

```kotlin
LazyColumn {
  item { ... }
  stickyHeader {
    ScrollableTabRow(...) { ... }
  }
  item { ... }
}
```

Comment: Yup, also saw it in the release, thanks for help!